# How to find which 2D points in an arrayList are collinear

Tags: java, arraylist, geometry

I have an arrayList that stores 2D points. When connecting these points together, they represent a route. I want to find which points are on the same line (collinear), so that I can know on which points do turns/corners occur. An example would be:

```
ArrayList<Point> positions = new ArrayList<Point>();
positions.add(Point(0,0));
positions.add(Point(0,1));
positions.add(Point(0,2));
positions.add(Point(1,2));
positions.add(Point(2,2));
positions.add(Point(3,3));
```

Picture of example:

[image]

I want to be able to know that in this example, points `C`, `D`, `E` and `G` are where "turns" occur, while points `A,B,C`, `C,D`, `D,E`, `E,F,G` and `G,H` are collinear.

My idea is to first sample three points and check the slope. If the slope does not match I know that the third point is not collinear with the first two. If they do, I know that they are collinear, and I check more points until the slope does not match. Then I know what the first line ends, the second line starts, and where the turn occurs. I repeat this process. However I have not had an idea of how to implement this. I would really appreciate any help.

Edit: I only have integer coordinates, and two consecutive points always have a Chebyshev distance of 1. Thanks to @Marco13.

Comment: Do all points have integer coordinates?

Comment: The cross product of two of the vectors formed by 3 collinear points is equal to zero: for instance, from your drawing: ABxAC = 0 ==> points A, B, C are collinear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** compute the slope when there are vertical lines involved.

From the image, and the description, I assume that you only have integer coordinates, and that two consecutive points always have a [Chebyshev distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance) of 1. (If this is not the case, you should edit your answer and include more information).

Then, a point (x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>) is a turning point when

- x<sub>i-1</sub> - x<sub>i</sub> != x<sub>i+1</sub> - x<sub>i</sub> **and**
- y<sub>i-1</sub> - y<sub>i</sub> != y<sub>i+1</sub> - y<sub>i</sub>

I'd personally recommend to compute the *indices* of these points in the list, because this has several advantages:

- You won't run into trouble when the same point appears multiple times
- You can easily look up the points in the list when you have the index
- You can use consecutive turning point indices to compute the sublists of points that are collinear

This is implemented here as an example:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TurningPoints
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        points.add(createPoint("A", 1, 0));
        points.add(createPoint("B", 1, 1));
        points.add(createPoint("C", 1, 2));
        points.add(createPoint("D", 2, 2));
        points.add(createPoint("E", 3, 1));
        points.add(createPoint("F", 4, 1));
        points.add(createPoint("G", 5, 1));
        points.add(createPoint("H", 5, 2));

        List<Integer> indices = computeTurningPointIndices(points);
        System.out.println("Turning points are at " + indices);

        List<Point> turningPoints = indices.stream().map(i -> points.get(i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println("They are " + turningPoints);

        System.out.println("Collinear:");
        indices.add(0, 0);
        indices.add(points.size() - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < indices.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            int i0 = indices.get(i);
            int i1 = indices.get(i + 1);
            List<Point> collinear = points.subList(i0, i1 + 1);

            System.out.println("    " + collinear);
        }
    }

    private static List<Integer> computeTurningPointIndices(List<Point> points)
    {
        List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i < points.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            Point prev = points.get(i - 1);
            Point curr = points.get(i);
            Point next = points.get(i + 1);
            int dxPrev = prev.x - curr.x;
            int dyPrev = prev.y - curr.y;
            int dxNext = next.x - curr.x;
            int dyNext = next.y - curr.y;
            if (dxPrev != dxNext && dyPrev != dyNext)
            {
                indices.add(i);
            }
        }
        return indices;
    }

    private static Point createPoint(String name, int x, int y)
    {
        // Only for this example. You should usually not do this!
        return new Point(x, y)
        {
            @Override
            public String toString()
            {
                return name + "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
            }
        };
    }

}
```

The output is

```
Turning points are at [2, 3, 4, 6]
They are [C(1,2), D(2,2), E(3,1), G(5,1)]
Collinear:
    [A(1,0), B(1,1), C(1,2)]
    [C(1,2), D(2,2)]
    [D(2,2), E(3,1)]
    [E(3,1), F(4,1), G(5,1)]
    [G(5,1), H(5,2)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason I get `error: incompatible types: List<Integer> cannot be converted to int` on the line finding turning points with the indices. I am unsure what happened. I think `i` should be an `int`, right?

Comment: @CalvinXu The program that I posted can be compiled and run. What did you change?

Comment: @Marcu13 I apologize it seems to have been a problem with the Android project I was working on. Now it works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

By calculating the changes of slope for each adjacent pair in the list 
you can get the points where "turns" occur. 
Java can take care of vertical lines by calculating the slope as "*Infinity*", 
 so don't worry about it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Point> positions = new ArrayList<Point>();
    positions.add(new Point(1,0));
    positions.add(new Point(1,1));
    positions.add(new Point(1,2));
    positions.add(new Point(2,2));
    positions.add(new Point(3,1));
    positions.add(new Point(4,1));
    positions.add(new Point(5,1));
    positions.add(new Point(5,2));

    ArrayList<Point> turns = new ArrayList<Point>();
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++) {
        turns.add(null);
    }

    int counter = 0;
    if (positions.size() > 2) {
        Point base = positions.get(0);
        Point next = positions.get(1);
        int x = (next.x - base.x);
        double slope = 1.0 * (next.y - base.y) / (next.x - base.x);

        for (int i = 2; i < positions.size(); i++) {
            Point newpoint = positions.get(i);

            double newslope = 1.0 * (newpoint.y - next.y) / (newpoint.x - next.x);
            if (newslope != slope) {
                counter++;
                turns.set(i - 1, positions.get(i - 1));
                slope = newslope;
            }

            next = newpoint;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Collinear points:");
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print("(" + positions.get(i).x + ", " + positions.get(i).y + ") ");
        if (turns.get(i) != null) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("(" + positions.get(i).x + ", " + positions.get(i).y + ") ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    if (counter > 0) {
        System.out.println("Turns at these points: ");
        for (Point p : turns) {
            if (p != null)
                System.out.print("(" + p.x + ", " + p.y + ") ");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("There are no turns!");
    }
}
```

will print:

```
Collinear points:
(1, 0) (1, 1) (1, 2) 
(1, 2) (2, 2) 
(2, 2) (3, 1) 
(3, 1) (4, 1) (5, 1) 
(5, 1) (5, 2) 

Turns at these points: 
(1, 2) (2, 2) (3, 1) (5, 1)
```

Comment: Yes, division by zero

Comment: Thank you so much. I ultimately went with the other solution, but I really appreciate this as well.